# repeat-while operator in rx-swift

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I have a function that fires an API request to the server. I want to loop over it until it returns `false` (*no more data*).

```
func getData(id: Int) -> Observable<Bool> {
     return Observable.create { observer in
           // Alamofire request
           // parse data
           // if can decode, 
           //   return true and increment page's property 
           // otherwise false
           // error, if there's a problem
     }
}
```

- First try: I've tried using `takeWhile`, like : `getData(id).takeWhile {$0}`. It only iterate over my function 1x only.
- Second try: using a range. The problem here is that even if my `getData` function errors out, instead of stopping, the loop continues !

  ```
  Observable.range(start: 1, count: 100)
    .enumerated()
    .flatMapLatest({ _ in
          self.getData(someID)
    })
    .subscribe(onNext: { _ in
         // save to DB
         observer.onNext(true)
         observer.onCompleted()
     }, onError: { error in
         observer.onError(error)
     })
     .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
  ```

Is there a way to do it, `rx` style ?

Comment: Use `takeUntil { $0 != nil }` that should help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
let callApiTrigger = BehaviorRelay<Bool>(value: true)

let callApiEnoughTimes = callApiTrigger.asObservable()
    .takeWhile { $0 }
    .flatMap { _ in
        return getData(someId)
    }
    .do(onNext: { (apiResult: Bool) in
        callApiTrigger.accept(apiResult)
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why `takeWhile` and `take(X)` do not work, is because they do not resubscribe to the Observable. A network request observable typically emits *one* value at the most.

What you are looking for requires some form of recursion / resubscribing. If you want to it hardcore Rx I suggest you reverse engineer the `retry` operator to suit your needs. Although I consider myself experienced with RxSwift, that seems like a bridge too far.

Fortunately, I whipped up a recursive approach that works just fine too :)

```swift
class PageService {
    typealias Page = (pageNumber: Int, items: [String]?)

    private func getPage(_ pageNumber: Int) -> Observable<Page> {
        let pageToReturn = Page(pageNumber: pageNumber, items: (pageNumber < 3) ? ["bert, henk"] : nil)

        return Observable<Page>
            .just(pageToReturn)
            .delay(0.5, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    }

    func allPagesFollowing(pageNumber: Int) -> Observable<Page> {
        let objectToReturnInCaseOfError = Page(pageNumber: pageNumber + 1, items: nil)

        return getPage(pageNumber + 1)
            // in order to error out gracefully, you could catch the network error and interpret it as 0 results
            .catchErrorJustReturn(objectToReturnInCaseOfError)
            .flatMap { page -> Observable<Page> in
                // if this page has no items, do not continue the recursion
                guard page.items != nil else { return .empty() }

                // glue this single page together with all the following pages
                return Observable<Page>.just(page)
                    .concat(self.allPagesFollowing(pageNumber: page.pageNumber))
        }
    }
}

_ = PageService().allPagesFollowing(pageNumber: 0)
    .debug("get page")
    .subscribe()
```

This will print:

```
2018-03-30 11:56:24.707: get page -> subscribed
2018-03-30 11:56:25.215: get page -> Event next((pageNumber: 1, data: Optional(["bert, henk"])))
2018-03-30 11:56:25.718: get page -> Event next((pageNumber: 2, data: Optional(["bert, henk"])))
2018-03-30 11:56:26.223: get page -> Event completed
2018-03-30 11:56:26.223: get page -> isDisposed
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, the `.concat` is a really nice trick here. Also, I have added `            .toArray().compactMap({ $0.flatMap { $0 }})` to collect my results to a single response.